# Determine loader jar of a dynamically loaded jar

Tags: java

How do I determine the name of the jar that is dynamically loading my jar? Is it possible? I have attempted many variants using ClassLoader but with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Let me explain why I need the name of the "loader jar". In our container we have the following lines:

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { artifact.getFile().toURI().toURL() });
Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(classLoader, artifact.getArtifact().getFile().toURI().toURL());
Class<?> processorClass = classLoader.loadClass(className);
Object processorClassInstance =  processorClass.newInstance();
```

When the loaded class is instantiated, newInstance above, it's properties files is external to the jar the class resides. The configuration files are in a directory named after the container jar that contains the class that executed the lines of code above. So, if the deployed container jar is called RedcapTDP.jar the configuration files are in "C:...\RedcapTDP". When the RedcapTDP.jar is deployed it dynamically loads the configured maven artifact which in turn will read it's configuration file from the RedcapTDP directory.

I hope that makes it clear!

Comment: `Class<?> processorClass = classLoader.loadClass(className);` so the class returned by this line, when instatiated needs to load config from a directory dependent on THE NAME of the `artifact` that you know above?

Comment: It will load a config from a directory dependent on the name of the jar which contains the class that executes that line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I determine the name of the jar that is dynamically loading my jar? Is it possible?

Taking you literally, no, it is clearly impossible.  In fact, it doesn't even make sense.  Java does not "load" Jars at all, though it may load one or more classes contained within a jar.  When it does so, it is the VM loading the class, not any jar loading it.

Interpreting you a bit more liberally, perhaps you are asking "how do I determine the *class* whose dependency on one of the classes in my jar is causing my class to be loaded, and how do I determine from which jar file that other class was loaded?"  Unless your control extends beyond the classes in your jar, however, this is again impossible.

Class *loading* is a separate step preceding class initialization, and class initialization is the first point at which there is any opportunity to execute any code contained in your class.  Thus, class loading is no longer ongoing when your classes first get a chance to inquire about anything.  Moreover, classes are not necessarily loaded from jars at all, and in any event, they do not carry information about the source from which they were loaded.

I could perhaps go further afield with speculations about what you may mean to ask, but I don't see any interpretation of the question that affords an answer different from "no, it is not possible."

Comment: See above. I edited the post to describe why I need the name of the container jar.

Comment: It doesn't matter *why* you want it, @user481779.  The Rolling Stones have some words for you: you can't always get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the unequivocal answer. I guess we'll find another way. Thanks again for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

JARs don't load JARs. A jar file is just a meaningless container that helps holding class files and other resources together. Classes are loaded by a class loader(s) from a class path provided to the jvm. What you're trying to do is not possible. Maybe you can explain what you're trying to achieve and perhaps there is a better way to do it.

Comment: See above. I edited the post to describe why I need the name of the container jar.